# Knockout does not load my UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, knockout.js

Hello I'm new using Knockout.js . I'm trying to load some data that I get from my API (Json format) in my HTML templates using knockout.js

Here is the .js that I developed.

```
function cronologiaViewModel() {

var self = this;

self.publicaciones = ko.observableArray();

self.current_page = 1

load = function() {
    cargarCronologia();
}

cargarCronologia = function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET"
        url : '/timeline/get_privada/',
        dataType : "json",

        beforeSend : function() {
        },
        success : function(data) {
            index = 0;
            data.results.forEach(function (element) {
                element.created_relative  = moment(element.fecha).fromNow();                    
                //element.comments_count = element.comments.length
                //element.can_delete = element.owner.username.valueOf() == self.current_user.valueOf()

                ko_element = ko.mapping.fromJS(element);
                self.publicaciones.push(ko_element);
            }); 
        }
    });

}

cronologiaVM = cronologiaViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(cronologiaVM);
```

And here it's the place in my template where I want to put the data that I'm getting using data-bind.

```
<!-- beginning of the Post-->
            <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                <div class="bubble">
                 <div class="pointer" data-bind="foreach: publicaciones">
                    <p data-bind="text: contenido" > A Personal Post</p>
                </div>
                  <div class="pull-left">Publicado hace:</div>
                  <div class="pointer-border"></div>
                </div><!-- bubble end -->
                <br>
                <p class="post-actions"> <a href="#">Me Gusta</a> - <a href="#">Compartir</a> </p>
                <div class="comment-form">
                  <form class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group, col-sm-8">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Ingrese su comentario">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Comentar</button>
                  </form>
                </div><!-- comment form end -->

               <!-- End Post-->
```

The script that I'm using

```
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript "></script>
    <!-- Director App -->
    <script src="js/Director/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script async src="js/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
   <script async src="js/socialUcla/cronologia.js"></script>
```

"Contenido" is an attribute object that the Json provides.

```
  My Json

{  "id": 1,
    "contenido": "Mi primer Post",
    "fecha": "2017-02-11T20:46:14.050475Z"}
```

[The error that I get in the Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSine.png)

Comment: When you say it doesn't load your UI is the page blank or does it load partially, but with errors? Are there any errors in your browser console?

Comment: page in blank. 
How can I see errors in my browser console?
Is there a way to know if the observableArray is being filled?

Comment: the console depends on which browser. in IE it's F12. In Chrome it's Ctrl+Shift+i

Comment: If this is an exact paste of the code you're using then there are a couple of typos that might be causing the page to not load. The $.ajax call needs a comma after "type: 'get'", and there must be a curly brace missing at the end of your cronologiaViewModel

Comment: I get this error in the browser consoles: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <     cronologia.js:3

Comment: I just tried your suggestions but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Here's a link to a jsFiddle where I've tried to recreate your code but I had to make some assumptions to get it working. Let me know if it looks right. https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/6rte44gm/

Comment: It' something like that. But I have to use the json that the URL provides.
It code in the link works, I copied in my project and it didn't work. In the console appears the same error. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: I can't recreate your json, but the general structure should match. Functions are in the right places etc. You'll see I had to add "self." In front of some of them

Comment: Does your console tell you which line number the error is on?

Comment: I just edited the question to put an example of the JSON. I dont know why still doesn't work with the changes you made.

Comment: This is the error: 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <                 cronologia.js:3

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle to use your json data: https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/6rte44gm/

Comment: What happens if you try replacing your cronologiaViewModel with the one in my example?

Comment: Doesn't work either. I just tried it. 
I found out that the error that I get in the browser console is because the interpreter was expecting json, but it received < or HTML. I saw that in the network developer tab. I don.t know how to fix that.

Comment: Your code is working good. Maybe my error is in my HTML template. I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes that sounds like the problem is on the API side. There's a tool called fiddler that can let you inspect the data as it's being sent between the server and client. It often helps to know exactly what your api is sending you. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: I'm going to inspect my data. But either way, it should work with data that I'm defining in the var data of the .js

Comment: You're right it absolutely should. If you get the same error setting the data locally then it's not the json api call. Are you using asynchronous loading for your html templates too? Any chance you can post more of your code?

Comment: How do I know if I'm using asynchronous loading ? What else of my code should I post?

Comment: By asynchronous loading I mean your html template is defined in a separate html file that is loaded at runtime using a module loading library like require.js. If that doesn't sound familiar then it's probably just in a script block inside your primary html file. I'd like to see more of your html I guess. Right now all I know about is the contenido div and not anything surrounding it.

Comment: Yes I'm defining the html templates in a separate file from my java script file. I just posted more of my html code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/6rte44gm/8/ Unfortunately everything still works for me haha. I'm running out of ideas, but what version of the knockout/jquery/bootstrap/moment libraries are you using?

Comment: I'm running out of ideas too. Knockout version: 3.1.0, jquery version: 2.1.4, bootsrap verison: 3.0.3 and moment version: 2.17.0.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jlspake/6rte44gm/9/ That wasn't it either.

Comment: I'm sorry for the missing code. Do you think it may be a compatible problems between versions?

Comment: I didn't think it was likely but it was worth checking at this point.

Comment: Can I send my project to you to check it out?

Comment: I'd be happy to take a look at it. I don't see a way to private message so here's a temporary email address you can use: qjov@kusrc.com

Comment: I just sent you the code. Thank you so much.